# Reports and logs doesn't appear in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

I use Pycharm to run my robot test scripts and when I run the script I cannot find the report and log for relevant run Is there any specific configuration need to be done to get those?

Comment: Ever taken a look into user guide? http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#output-directory

Comment: As in real life as well as on [SO] it is context that makes the difference. In the above [How do I do X](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253069/whats-the-appropriate-new-current-close-reason-for-how-do-i-do-x) question the obvious reply will be to ask for your research efforts and any other thing you've tried or dismissed. Adding this information will save us from asking and in the end will ensure you get the response(s) you need from the community.